# Visual Studio Extention - Context Menu for 'Server Explorer'

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

In a VSIX project, in the .vsct file I can see how to target different objects and provide a custom context menu:

For instance, the following will target an item node in the solution explorer:

```
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE"/>
    <!--<Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS"/>-->
  </Group>
```

Changing the id property from `IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE` to `IDM_VS_CTXT_CODEWIN` will result in the context menu appearing in the code window instead.

This is documented here: 
[Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsmenus.aspx)

However, I would like my context menu to appear in the 'Server Explorer' instead. An example and a link to the documentation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find Visual Studio menu guids, this usually works.
In your registry set EnableVSIPLogging DWORD to 1, under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\General`.

Restart Visual Studio (and computer?) and hold Ctrl+Shift and right click an item in the server explorer, it will open a dialog window with something like this:

[image]

You can go from there.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, I can't find that key under 14.0/General or with a search. I'm using VS 2015 Professional.

Comment: You have to create it "EnableVSIPLogging" DWord = 1

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Paul Swetz and James Sinclair I was able to get this working.

Using the method described by Paul Swetz I could identify the guid required for the Server Window object I was clicking, in this case the table node.

Having got that I added that id to the Symbols in the .vsct file, with a name of my choice:

```
<GuidSymbol name="guidWhatever" value="{d4f02a6a-c5ae-4bf2-938d-f1625bdca0e2}"> <!--//server explorer - table-->
  <IDSymbol name="IDMX_DV_OBJECT_NODE" value="0x8200"/>
</GuidSymbol>
```

Now I can use that in Groups and the custom command appears in the dropdown.

```
<Groups> 
  <Group guid="guidFirstCommandPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
    <!--<Parent guid="{D309F791-903F-11D0-9EFC-00A0C911004F}" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE"/>-->
    <Parent guid="guidWhatever" id="IDMX_DV_OBJECT_NODE"/>
  </Group>
</Groups>
```

The only problem now is identifying and accessing the selected table and database but that's another matter.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to determine what the selected table and database were?

Comment: I didn't, I'm afriad.

Answer (score 1):

All of VS 2015's commands, menus, toolbars etc are detailed in a couple of c++ header files (stdidcmd.h and vsshlids.h).

On my install they are in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Inc'.

Had a very brief look in the files and i think you'll need something starting

- IDG_SE_CONTEXT_ to target groups within the server explorer context menu
- IDG_SE_TOOLBAR_ to get into the toolbar
- IDM_SE_CONTEXT_ to get to the context menu
- IDM_SE_TOOLBAR_ to get to the toolbar menu

Comment: Thanks to the two answers I was able to get this working, but it required an extra step, outlined below.