# Creating visual studio extensions for table nodes in the Server Explorer Data Connections

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I would like to add a custom command to the context menu of each node that appears for every table in a sql server database listed in the Server Explorer.

[image: Server Explorer]

I've gone through a basic tutorial and added a command to the tools menu bar as well as a custom top level menu.

I've also seen the tutorial [Extending the Server Explorer to Display Web Parts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256699.aspx) which is very close to what I want to do, but it is specific to the sharepoint connections node, and uses the sharepoint specific IExplorerNodeTypeExtension interfaces.  I'm having trouble finding any documentation pertaining to the data connections node.  Can anyone provide any references to relevant documentation or information on what interfaces I should be leveraging?

Comment: Like Carlos J's suggestion here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6e43cd5a-f0b1-4e05-8dc8-f5509590e28f/server-explorer-extension?forum=vsx, it seems that you need to find the Guid:Id of the group on the context menu using the EnableVSIPLogging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some hints from Jack Zhai and a few other web resources I was able to track down information.

- [Stack Overflow - Context menu for Server Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508063/visual-studio-extention-context-menu-for-server-explorer/39538293)
- [MSDN blog - How to add custom menu to vs editor window](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsx/2016/04/21/how-to-add-a-custom-paste-special-command-to-the-vs-editor-menu/)
- [MSDN Blog - Using EnableVSIPLogging to identify menus and commands with VS 2005](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dr._ex/2007/04/17/using-enablevsiplogging-to-identify-menus-and-commands-with-vs-2005-sp1/)

So first, I enabled VSIPLogging by setting the EnableVSIPLogging to 1 in Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio###\General

[image: Enable VSIPLogging registry key]

Then I was able to determine what the guids and ids of any menu item or tree node in Visual Studio by holding down CTRL + SHIFT and right clicking on it.

[image]

From this I was able to determine that the top level nodes in the server explorer had a Guid of {74D21310-2AEE-11D1-8BFB-00A0C90F26F7} with a command id of 1283.

Object nodes in the server explorer (such as Tables, stored procedures, etc) have a Guid of {d4f02a6a-c5ae-4bf2-938d-f1625bdca0e2} and a command id of 33280 (0x8200)

Object node parents in the server explorer (such as the static "Tables", "Stored procedures", nodes that categorize the object nodes) have a guid of {d4f02a6a-c5ae-4bf2-938d-f1625bdca0e2} and a command id of 33024 (0x8100)

So with these Guids I can now attach my commands where I want.

I want a command that is specific to an individual table, and a command that is specific to all tables in the database so I will use a d4f02a6a-c5ae-4bf2-938d-f1625bdca0e2 with command id of 0x8200 and a Guid of d4f02a6a-c5ae-4bf2-938d-f1625bdca0e2 with command id of 0x8100.

Next I need to define these values in my vsct file of my VSIX project so I add them to the symbols section:

[image: VSCT symbols]

I add 2 command items to my project and then I need to change the parent of the groups so they appear on the correct area in the server explorer:

[image: VSCT groups]

Now, the database command does appear for all static object nodes, even though I want it to only appear on the "Tables" node, and the table command appears for all object nodes and their, even though I want it to appear only for the table node itself.  I believe that needs to be solved in code somehow, dynamically determining the visibility of the command menu item, but I'll have to figure that one one separately.

Below is the vsct in its entirety:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CommandTable xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005-10-18/CommandTable" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <!--  This is the file that defines the actual layout and type of the commands.
        It is divided in different sections (e.g. command definition, command
        placement, ...), with each defining a specific set of properties.
        See the comment before each section for more details about how to
        use it. -->

  <!--  The VSCT compiler (the tool that translates this file into the binary
        format that VisualStudio will consume) has the ability to run a preprocessor
        on the vsct file; this preprocessor is (usually) the C++ preprocessor, so
        it is possible to define includes and macros with the same syntax used
        in C++ files. Using this ability of the compiler here, we include some files
        defining some of the constants that we will use inside the file. -->

  <!--This is the file that defines the IDs for all the commands exposed by VisualStudio. -->
  <Extern href="stdidcmd.h" />

  <!--This header contains the command ids for the menus provided by the shell. -->
  <Extern href="vsshlids.h" />

  <!--The Commands section is where commands, menus, and menu groups are defined.
      This section uses a Guid to identify the package that provides the command defined inside it. -->
  <Commands package="guidCRUDSPCommandsPackage">
    <!-- Inside this section we have different sub-sections: one for the menus, another
    for the menu groups, one for the buttons (the actual commands), one for the combos
    and the last one for the bitmaps used. Each element is identified by a command id that
    is a unique pair of guid and numeric identifier; the guid part of the identifier is usually
    called "command set" and is used to group different command inside a logically related
    group; your package should define its own command set in order to avoid collisions
    with command ids defined by other packages. -->

    <!-- In this section you can define new menu groups. A menu group is a container for
         other menus or buttons (commands); from a visual point of view you can see the
         group as the part of a menu contained between two lines. The parent of a group
         must be a menu. -->
    <Groups>

      <!-- Table scope -->
      <Group guid="guidCRUDSPCommandsPackageCmdSet1" id="TableMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
        <!--<Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS" />-->
        <Parent guid="guidServerExplorerObjectNode" id="IDMX_DV_OBJECT_NODE" />
      </Group>

      <!-- Database scope -->
      <Group guid="guidCRUDSPCommandsPackageCmdSet1" id="DatabaseMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
        <!--<Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS" />-->
        <Parent guid="guidServerExplorerObjectNode" id="IDMX_DV_STATIC_NODE" />
      </Group>

    </Groups>

    <!--Buttons section. -->
    <!--This section defines the elements the user can interact with, like a menu command or a button
        or combo box in a toolbar. -->
    <Buttons>
      <!--To define a menu group you have to specify its ID, the parent menu and its display priority.
          The command is visible and enabled by default. If you need to change the visibility, status, etc, you can use
          the CommandFlag node.
          You can add more than one CommandFlag node e.g.:
              <CommandFlag>DefaultInvisible</CommandFlag>
              <CommandFlag>DynamicVisibility</CommandFlag>
          If you do not want an image next to your command, remove the Icon node /> -->

      <Button guid="guidCRUDSPCommandsPackageCmdSet1" id="cmdidCmdTable" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidCRUDSPCommandsPackageCmdSet1" id="TableMenuGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPic1" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Command for Table</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>

      <Button guid="guidCRUDSPCommandsPackageCmdSet1" id="cmdidCmdDatabase" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidCRUDSPCommandsPackageCmdSet1" id="DatabaseMenuGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidImages1" id="bmpPic1" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Command for Database</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
    </Buttons>

    <!--The bitmaps section is used to define the bitmaps that are used for the commands.-->
    <Bitmaps>
      <!--  The bitmap id is defined in a way that is a little bit different from the others:
            the declaration starts with a guid for the bitmap strip, then there is the resource id of the
            bitmap strip containing the bitmaps and then there are the numeric ids of the elements used
            inside a button definition. An important aspect of this declaration is that the element id
            must be the actual index (1-based) of the bitmap inside the bitmap strip. -->


      <Bitmap guid="guidImages" href="Resources\CmdTable.png" usedList="bmpPic1, bmpPic2, bmpPicSearch, bmpPicX, bmpPicArrows, bmpPicStrikethrough" />
      <Bitmap guid="guidImages1" href="Resources\CmdDatabase.png" usedList="bmpPic1, bmpPic2, bmpPicSearch, bmpPicX, bmpPicArrows, bmpPicStrikethrough" />
    </Bitmaps>
  </Commands>

  <Symbols>
    <!-- {d4f02a6a-c5ae-4bf2-938d-f1625bdca0e2} is the object node in the server explorer -->
    <GuidSymbol name="guidServerExplorerObjectNode" value="{d4f02a6a-c5ae-4bf2-938d-f1625bdca0e2}">
      <!--server explorer - table-->
      <IDSymbol name="IDMX_DV_OBJECT_NODE" value="0x8200" />
      <IDSymbol name="IDMX_DV_STATIC_NODE" value="0x8100" />
    </GuidSymbol>

    <!-- {74D21310-2AEE-11D1-8BFB-00A0C90F26F7} is the server explorer -->
    <GuidSymbol name="guidServerExplorer" value="{74D21310-2AEE-11D1-8BFB-00A0C90F26F7}">
      <!--server explorer - table-->
      <IDSymbol name="IDMX_DV_SERVER_NODE" value="0x503" />
    </GuidSymbol>

    <!-- This is the package guid. -->
    <GuidSymbol name="guidCRUDSPCommandsPackage" value="{a71670bc-ef23-40a3-b8a0-ed872b79476c}" />

    <!-- Constants-->
    <GuidSymbol value="{946311de-35f2-4379-84e2-91867976faf8}" name="guidCRUDSPCommandsPackageCmdSet1">
      <IDSymbol value="256" name="cmdidCmdTable" />
      <IDSymbol value="257" name="cmdidCmdDatabase" />
      <IDSymbol value="258" name="TableMenuGroup" />
      <IDSymbol value="259" name="DatabaseMenuGroup" />
    </GuidSymbol>

    <GuidSymbol value="{679ecb35-41d9-4021-933b-ec6b25afc100}" name="guidImages">
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic1" value="1" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic2" value="2" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicSearch" value="3" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicX" value="4" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicArrows" value="5" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicStrikethrough" value="6" />
    </GuidSymbol>

    <GuidSymbol value="{9392ca3d-3400-4b7a-a691-7108032249cd}" name="guidImages1">
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic1" value="1" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic2" value="2" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicSearch" value="3" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicX" value="4" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicArrows" value="5" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicStrikethrough" value="6" />
    </GuidSymbol>
  </Symbols>
</CommandTable>
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, if it has been resolved, you could mark it as the answer. Have a nice day.

Comment: How were you able to access the data for each object in the MenuItemCallback function?

Comment: I have not been able to, and that is where my project sat, since I need to be able to access the underlying data, or somehow determine what table that node is representing.