# How to create a context menu for an instance of database in SQL Server object explorer

Tags: xml, visual-studio-extensions, server-explorer

I'm trying to create an extension that has a context menu for an instance of a database in SQL Server Object Explorer using Visual Studio 2017. For that, I need the GUID and id of SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio.

I'm tried the same in Solution Explorer using the id **IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE** in xml.

Please help me with the GUID and id of SQL Server Object Explorer. Thanks in advance

Comment: I got one issue before which shared about how to add the context menu for the Server Explorer windows here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928398/creating-visual-studio-extensions-for-table-nodes-in-the-server-explorer-data-co,I think it could provide you a path for this issue even if it was about the SQL Server object explorer window.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll look into it and let you know. Thanks again :)

Comment: What about this issue now? Would you please share the latest information in your side?

Comment: sorry for the delay Jack. I was not able to find the GUID and ID of SQL Server Object Explorer, but when I tried it for Server Explorer it did work well.

Comment: This official document shared us the GUID 
 or ID informaiton for windows in VS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc807687.aspx, it seems that it really has no it for the Sql Server object explorer window. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/224e788f-c060-4adb-8266-65f599dd6a1d/extending-sql-server-object-explorer-context-menus?forum=vsx