# Error in displaying the Extension in SSMS created in Visual Studio (VSIX project) when right clicking any tables

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, ssms, vscode-extensions, vsix

I am trying to create an extension for the tables in any database which will be shown when I right click on any tables in SSMS, I want to run that extension from there. Furthermore, I want my extension to make insert queries, delete queries or any other queries on their own when user clicks on any table (as of now to make it simple lets say it just only prints a message "hello world!"). Please help with the same for any reference or from where and how to start approaching this kind of thing.

I took reference from this link [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928398/creating-visual-studio-extensions-for-table-nodes-in-the-server-explorer-data-co)

here I have checked and replicated the .vsct file like this:
[VSCT file after replicating from the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYPNM.png)

from what I have seen from this it's kind of an structure so to how to display the extension command.

what I have done till now:
I took reference from the below links to first create an extension in SSMS tools bar using visual studio (VSIX project) and replicated the same as mentioned in the first link provided below:

1. [Detailed Explanation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1377559/How-to-Create-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-18-SSMS%22www.codeproject.com%22)
2. [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55661806/how-to-create-an-extension-for-ssms-2019-v18%22stackoverflow.com%22)
3. [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/visualstudio/extensibility/extensibility-hello-world?view=vs-2019%22learn.microsoft.com%22)

Also i have figured out how to find the GUID and GUID-ID when i press CLTR+SHIFT+Right click.

So now as this is done I am unable to understand how to approach the work I want to do as I mentioned above, since till now my extension is only visible in the tools menu which i don't want now i want it to be shown when I right click on any of my tables in the database. I know from the GUID i need to do something , but how that's the question and wanted to learn more about the structure of the above .vsct file. Also if i change the GUID and Ids as mentioned , how am i supposed to hit my method/action in the command file. Please help me understand this.